# PyTorch OOM error while half the GPU memory is free

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, detecto

I am training an object detection network using the detecto library.The dataset consists of RGB images of 50*50 pixels. The batch size is 2. When I run the code (using NeoVim as my IDE), I get this before the end of the first epoch:

> Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
> torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 132.00 MiB (GPU 0; 12.00 GiB total
> capacity; 2.07 GiB already allocated; 7.12 GiB free; 2.77 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

It seems that cuda is not using all the resources available. I was looking at the task manager while running the code, it stops even though half the GPU memory is still free.

Here are my computer specs: 16Gb RAM, Nvidia RTX 3060 (12 Gb), using Windows. I checked that cuda is using my GPU.

It seems to work with a batch size of 1, but of course this is not what I want, I was expecting to train at least batches of 8...
I also tried running the code with VSCode and also got an error.

Do someone know how to solve this issue ?